# Using Razor script within another razor script

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there a way to reuse a razor script within a razor script such that the @functions{...} in C# defined in the BaseRazorScript can be called in the razor script that is reusing the BaseRazorScript file?

Comment: Why don't you just create your own helper and use it wherever you need? That's what helpers are for, it would seem.

Comment: i want the ability of razor script (script = you can change the logic without compiling it. can you do that with helpers? i think not)

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Razor script gets compiled. When it's used in *.cshtml or *.vbhtml files, it looks like when a change is made there is no need to compile, but in reality, these views get recompiled and cached on first hit. This is done behind the scenes, and transparently to user.

Comment: How that is done becomes irrelevant but i don't need to use VS to build it. it is done automatically on the webserver...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a partial. So for example:

```
@Html.Partial("nameofyourparital.cshtml")
```

You would have to place your partial file in the **~/views/partial/** or **~/views/shared/** folder